# VBA - Passing variable between modules

Tags: vba, vb6, coreldraw

I'm new to VB6, and trying to write some macro in use for CorelDraw.

I have a variable that need to be passed from Class module to Standard module, in my Class Module "SaveOptClass" I have a public variable called IsSaved and it's set on the class module:

```
Public IsSaved As Boolean

Public Sub SaveFile()
If <some triggers> Then
    IsSaved = True
End If
```

In Standard module:

```
Sub DoSave()
Dim SaveClass As SaveOptClass
Set SaveClass = New SaveOptClass

If SaveClass.IsSaved = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Save
Else
    Form1.Show
End If 
End Sub
```

Basically I'm trying to pass "IsSaved" boolean value from class module to standard. (If IsSaved is true, save the document or else display a form.)

I have tested that the boolean is True when I executed the code, but I can't get the state to pass to the other module.

Is there something I miss here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have is syntactically correct and would do what you think but its not logically correct (unless you have omitted something) as you never call SaveFile() - so after creating a new instance of the class IsSave is always going to be false by default ...

Comment: That is because you are initializing the instance of `SaveOptClass` in `DoSave` and probably other methods too. I would suggest moving the declaration (`public saveClass as SaveOptClass`) and initialization (`Set SaveClass = New SaveOptClass`) to a place where it will execute only once (say inside a bas module). That way all other methods will share the single instance.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by @shahkalpesh the problem is that **you're not using a meaningful instance** of `SaveOptClass`.

In my opinion the best way to design this kind of dependency is by mean of a parameter in the routine is using it and avoid as much as possible the use of global variables.

In your case this brings to this rewriting:

```
' in someOtherModule
Public Sub DoSave(saveOptObj as SaveOptClass)
    If saveOptObj.IsSaved Then ' = True is unnecessary
        ActiveDocument.Save
    Else
        Form1.Show
    End If 
End Sub
```

The client code could be:

```
private saveOptObj as SaveOptClass

Public Sub SaveFile()

    If <some triggers> Then
        saveOptObj.IsSaved = True    
    End If

    ' ....      
    someOtherModule.DoSave(saveOptObj)      
    ' ...
```

Consider also, at this point, a renaming of `DoSave`, given that the actions taken suggest different semantics. In similar cases is preferable moving the `If Else` logic in the *caller*. Anyway, if you prefer to group actions with different semantics in the same routine you'd better use namings like `DoSaveOr<SomethingElse>`.